# Is it possible to construct a real number theory on Peano arithmetic?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

I know how to construct $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{N}$ in set theory. For example, the construction of $\mathbb{Z}$ is,
$$\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{N}^2/\sim$$
$$(a, b)\sim(c, d)\Leftrightarrow  a+d=b+c$$

However, I do not know how to construct tuples and quotients in PA.

Is it possible to construct $\mathbb{R}$ in Peano arithmetic?

Comment: If what you're interested in is developing real analysis in a weak logical framework, you may be interested in [reverse mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics). It's indeed difficult to even construct $\Bbb R$ in $\mathsf{PA}$, but this is in some sense more of a technical limitation than an intrinsic one. There are very palatable alternatives - the three systems up to and including $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ don't *really* "assume more" than PA - technically speaking, $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ is a *conservative extension* of $\mathsf{PA}$.

Answer (score 0):

See [Peano Axioms, it's possible construct a real number theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2902098/peano-axioms-its-possible-construct-a-real-number-theory)

Comment: That question is "Is it possible to construct ... without induction?" It is OK to use induction in My question.

Comment: @MathMan as long as it's first order arithmetic (PA), it's not sufficient to fully describe the real number set. Using the second order statement of induction, however, can describe the real number set as the set of subsets of N, but it's called the second order arithmetic instead